# C++ で二分木探索のコード作成中にsegmentation faultが出てしまいます。

Tags: c++

このサイトでの質問は初めてです。質問文に分かりにくい部分がありましたら、申し訳ありません。
C++で二分木探索を作ろうとしています。デバックをしたところ、
「class cell *insert2」の else if 以降でsegmentation faultが出てしまいました。
質問にお答え頂けると助かります！

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;


template<typename T>class table {
  class cell{
    public:
    const char *key;
    const T binding;
    cell * left;
    cell * right;
    cell(char *k, T v) : key(k), binding(v),left(NULL),right(NULL) {}
  };
  public:

  class cell *root;

  /* 新しいnodeの製作 */

  /* operator() の定義 */
  void operator()(char *key){
    if(search(root,key) == NULL){
        cout << "あります。" << endl;       
    }else{
        cout << "ありません。" << endl;
    }
    return;
  }

/* insertの定義 */
/*１個のオーバーロード*/
  void insert(char *key, T binding){
    root = insert2(root,key,binding);
    return;
  }
    
/* operator -= の定義 */
  void operator-=(char *key){
    if(search(root,key) == NULL){
        cout << "存在しません。" << endl;
    }else{
        root = dele(root,key);
    }
    return;
  }

/*表示*/
  void print(int indent){
    print_tree(root,indent);
    return;
  }

  private:
  class cell *make_node (char* key, T binding, class cell *left, class cell *right) {
  class cell *new_node;
  new_node = new cell(key,binding);
  new_node->left = left;
  new_node->right = right;
  return new_node;
  }

/*１個のオーバーロード*/
  class cell *insert2(class cell * tree, char* key, T binding) {
  if (tree == NULL){ tree = make_node(key, binding, NULL, NULL);}
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) > 0){ tree->left = insert2(tree->left, key, binding);}
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) < 0){ tree->right = insert2(tree->right, key, binding);}

  return tree;
  }

  class cell *search(class cell * tree, char* key) {
  if (tree == NULL) return NULL;
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) > 0) return search(tree->left, key);
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) < 0) return search(tree->right, key);
  else return tree;
  }

  class cell *dele(class cell * tree, char* key) {
  class cell *p, *c;

  if (tree == NULL) return NULL;
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) > 0) {
    tree->left = dele(tree->left, key);
    return tree;
  }
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) < 0) {
    tree->right = dele(tree->right, key);
    return tree;
  }
  else {
    if (tree->left == NULL) return tree->right;
    if (tree->right == NULL) return tree->left;
    for ( p = tree, c = tree->right; c->left != NULL; p = c, c = c->left);
    if (p == tree) 
      p->right = c->right;
    else
      p->left = c->right;
    c->left = tree->left;
    c->right = tree->right;
    free(tree);
    return c;
  }
  }

  void print_tree(class cell *tree, int indent) {
  int i;

  if (tree == NULL) return;
  for(i = 0; i < indent; i++) 
  cout<< "\t" ;
  cout <<"+" << tree->key <<":" << tree->binding <<endl;
  print_tree(tree->left, indent+1);
  print_tree(tree->right, indent+1);
  }
  
};

int main() {
  table<int>table1;
    struct cell *root = NULL;


  table1.insert("akashi", 65);
  table1.insert("watanabe", 70);
  table1.insert("tomizawa", 80);
  table1.insert("tahata", 55);
  table1.insert("takimoto", 90);
  table1.insert("Miyamoto", 80);
  table1.insert("iriyama", 60);
  table1.insert("katsurada", 40);
  table1.insert("noguchi", 40);
  table1.insert("sato", 95);
  table1.insert("matsuzawa", 20);
  table1.print(0);
  table1("tahata");
  table1-=("tahata");
  table1.print(0);
  table1("tahata");
}
```

Comment: 「質問にお答え頂けると助かります！」とはありますが、肝心の質問は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

質問としては「何故segmentation faultが出る(発生する)のか教えて欲しい」とか、「何処をどう修正すれば良いのか教えて欲しい」と言ったところでしょうか？

以下のような感じに最初の`table1.insert(...)`を呼び出した先でエラーが発生していますね。

```
int main() {
  table<int>table1;
    struct cell *root = NULL;

  table1.insert("akashi", 65);
```

↓

```
template<typename T>class table {
...
  class cell *root;
...
/* insertの定義 */
/*１個のオーバーロード*/
  void insert(char *key, T binding){
    root = insert2(root,key,binding);
    return;
  }
```

↓

```
/*１個のオーバーロード*/
  class cell *insert2(class cell * tree, char* key, T binding) {
  if (tree == NULL){ tree = make_node(key, binding, NULL, NULL);}
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) > 0){ tree->left = insert2(tree->left, key, binding);}  // ←ここでエラー
  else if (strcmp(tree->key, key) < 0){ tree->right = insert2(tree->right, key, binding);}

  return tree;
  }
```

デバッガで実行したとしても、単にエラーが発生したことだけを見ているのでは、観察眼が不足していると言えるでしょう。
デバッガ上で何へのアクセスでsegmentation faultが発生したのか表示されているか、あるいはエラーが発生して停止した時点で調査が出来るはずです。

現象としてはこの時点でパラメータとして渡されたtree(ポインタ)の値が異常で、そこにアクセスしようとしてエラーになっています。
そしてtreeパラメータには呼び出し元でrootが指定されていて、それは良く見ると1度も初期化されていないことが分かります。

もしかしたら`int main()`の2行目`struct cell *root = NULL;`で初期化のつもりだったのかもしれませんが、これでは`table<int>table1;`とは何の関係も無い変数を定義して初期化しているだけです。
この行の位置で記述するなら、`table1.root = NULL;`となるでしょう。

より良いのは、`template<typename T>class table {...}`にコンストラクタを定義して、その中で`class cell *root;`に`NULL`を設定することのはずです。